# What is the proper way of mocking ResponseEntity<T>?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I am writing a unit test cases to test the rest service. It seems like I am mocking everything this is needed for the testcase to pass but unfortunately its failing and I am still getting null-pointer exception at

```
 when(restTemplate.exchange(
                ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
                any(HttpMethod.class),
                any(),
                ArgumentMatchers.<Class<RateResponse>>any()))
                .thenReturn(serviceResponse);
```

Also, I am unable to pass the data in responseentity ( honestly I dont know why )

RateServiceTest .class

```
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class RateServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private RateResponse rateResponse;

    @InjectMocks
    private RateService rateService = new RateService();

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @BeforeAll
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRateService() throws Exception {
        ResponseEntity<RateResponse> serviceResponse = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);

        Rate rate1 = new Rate();
        rate1.setOriginId("0100");
        rate1.setDestinationId("0200");

        Rate rate2 = new Rate();
        rate2.setOriginId("0300");
        rate2.setDestinationId("0400");

        List<Rate> rateList = new ArrayList<>();
        rateList.add(rate1);
        rateList.add(rate2);

        when(restTemplate.exchange(
                ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
                any(HttpMethod.class),
                any(),
                ArgumentMatchers.<Class<RateResponse>>any()))
                .thenReturn(serviceResponse);
        when(rateService.mapResponseToRows(any(RateResponse.class))).thenReturn(rateList);
        List<Rate> rateResponse = rateService.getRates();

        assertNotNull(rateResponse);

    }
}
```

RateResponse.class its a simple pojo class

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "status", "data" })
public class RateResponse {

    @JsonProperty("status")
    private String status;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Object data;

    @JsonProperty("status")
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    @JsonProperty("status")
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

getRates method

```
public List<Rate> getRates() {
        ResponseEntity<RateResponse> response;
        try{
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add("Authorization", computeAuthHeader());
            HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
            response =  restTemplate.exchange(rateURL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, RateResponse.class);
            List<Rate> rateList = mapResponseToRows(response.getBody());
            LOGGER.info("Response from RateService : " + response.getBody().toString());
            return rateList ;
        }
        catch(RateAccessException exception) {
            throw new RateAccessException(exception.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

and service is just another std service getting data from endpoint.

I was following some threads and other solutions available on stack overflow and google but none of them worked so far. I want to know if I am not mocking all the required dependencies correctly or I am messing up with my data types or is there something else that I missed completely while writing the test case.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your `rateService.getRates()` mehtod

Comment: Hi @haoyuwang i updated the question with getRates method

Comment: Are you sure? I didn't see it.

Comment: yes there was some issue with my network connection, sorry for that!

Comment: I would suggest to use http://wiremock.org/ instead of trying to mock the API call yourself.

Comment: It rather looks like an integration test as you use a RestTemplate.
You can write a real unit test on your service methods if you will.
Or compare status codes and deserialized entity to check if it match with your expected data. Can you provide the stacktrace of the NPE of your failing test ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I just add some mock data and modified my test case a little bit. Finally, its working now.

```
  @Test
    public void testRateService1() throws Exception
    {
        RateResponse response = new RateResponse();
        List<Map<String, String>> rowList = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, String> rowMap = new HashMap<>();
        rowMap.put("ORIGIN_ID", "123");
        rowMap.put("DESTINATION ID", "DEST1");
        rowList.add(rowMap);
        Map<String, Object> rowsMap = new HashMap<>();
        rowsMap.put("rows", rowList);
        Map<String, Object> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
        dataMap.put("query", rowsMap);
        response.setData(dataMap);
        response.setStatus("success");

        ResponseEntity<RateResponse> templateResponse = new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
        
        when(restTemplate.exchange(
                ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),
                any(HttpMethod.class),
                any(),
                ArgumentMatchers.<Class<RateResponse>>any()))
               .thenReturn(templateResponse);

        List<Rate> rateList = rateService.getRates();
        Assert.assertEquals(1, rateList.size());
        Assert.assertEquals("DEST1", rateList.get(0).getDestinationId());
    }
```